# Not found class error in running executable jar file (exported RMI application with eclipse)

Tags: java, jar, rmi

I have a project that a RMI application.
When I could successfully test them under eclipse (with [RMI Plugin](http://www.genady.net/rmi/)), I tried to export them as jar file with eclipse's export function.

The issue is that only one application works fine with the exported jar file.

```
java -jar registry.jar

java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: common.Registry <-- ???
```

The error message shows that class is not found. I unzip the jar file to find that the class is well exported in the jar file.

```
temp> unzip registry.jar 
Archive:  registry.jar
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF    
   creating: client/
  inflating: client/ChatClientImpl.class  
   creating: common/
  inflating: common/ChatRoomProvider.class  
  inflating: common/Entity.class     
  inflating: common/ChatRoomServer.class  
  inflating: common/ChatClient.class  
  inflating: common/Registry.class  <<<---
```

And this is the message caught from rmiregistry:

```
Exception dispatching call to [0:0:0, 0] in thread 
"RMI TCP Connection(2)-146.6.53.181" at Sun Nov 03 20:33:25 CST 2013:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: common.Registry
```

This is the code where error occurs:

```
try {
    // clients and providers can access with the name Registry
    Naming.rebind("Registry", new RegistryImpl()); <--
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What might be the problem? Why the jar file cannot find the class file in its jar file?

### ADDED

The temporary solution is as follows:

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/WHERE_THE_BIN_IS/bin/ -jar registry.jar
```

I could explicitly point to the codebase directory, but the same code is already in the jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved when I execute the rmiregister and set the CLASSPATH where the codebase is located.

```
export CLASSPATH=SOMEWHERE_THE_LOCAL_BASE_IS_LOCATED
rmiregistry
```